Why does Brown-Forsythe test return different results in bf.test (onewaytests) and leveneTest(..., center = median)?
I am using the lmertree function from the glmertree package to compare the effects of three contexts (levels of a factor called 'source') on acceleration.
Because visual inspection showed heteroscedasticity, I decided to log transform my dependent variable 'acceleration'. Though visual inspection shows improvement, I notice that leveneTest still points to a significant difference.
A colleague suggested using Brown–Forsythe test instead. We both tried but with different functions and obtained different results:

Using the bf.test function from 'onewaytests', no significant difference is found.
using the leveneTest while specifying the parameter 'center = median' still results in a significant difference.

I am wondering what is causing the difference between the two test results. Many thanks for your help!
Here is the code:
# Add a new column with log-transformed values of acceleration
CA_degrees_PT$log_acce_RHwri_norm_mean <- log(CA_degrees_PT$acce_RHwri_norm_mean)

log_acce_RHwri_norm_mean_lmertree <- lmertree(log_acce_RHwri_norm_mean ~ 1|duration_nFrames + (1|participant)|source , data = CA_degrees_PT) 
plot(log_acce_RHwri_norm_mean_lmertree, which = "tree", gp = gpar(cex = .9))

hist(residuals(log_acce_RHwri_norm_mean_lmertree))

qqnorm(residuals(log_acce_RHwri_norm_mean_lmertree))
qqline(residuals(log_acce_RHwri_norm_mean_lmertree))

resids_log_acce <- residuals(log_acce_RHwri_norm_mean_lmertree)
preds_log_acce <- predict(log_acce_RHwri_norm_mean_lmertree)
plot(CA_degrees_PT$source, resids_log_acce)

leveneTest(resids_log_acce ~ groups, center = median)
bf.test(resids_log_acce ~ groups, data = CA_degrees_PT)


I would think the Levene test with the central measure being means should be paid heed if you are using a least squares type of analysis (as you are). What is not clear, to me at least, is where groups is being defined.

It is not necessary for the Levene test to not have a significant difference. The within group variances are never going to be exactly equal. You just need to not violate the assumption of equal within-group variances too severely.
